# How can use previous button on action bar

Tags: android

I want to use the action bar previous button. I added this xml inside activities in manifest :

```
android:parentActivityName="com.dariran.SearchActivity"
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="com.dariran.SearchActivity" />
```

But when i compiled my project the previous page icon was displaying and when i clicked it is not working.

The LogCat return the error:

> tag name : Provider/Settings. and message : from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow from android website

```
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your target API? If you are developing for Android 4.0 and upper you have to add the tag android:parentActivityName. Try this:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Principal"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_principal"
            android:parentActivityName=".Programas" >

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Programas" />
        </activity>
```

UPDATE

Add this in you onCreate method:

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: Are you using the new Toolbar or the ActionBar?

Comment: @soheila Check the update in my answer. If it was useful for you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.2 and above the `android:parentActivityName` attribute is read and everything works out of the box. To support older platforms you must define the home action handling yourself:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` method will either read the standard attribute on Android 4.2 or above and execute native code for going up the activity stack or use a support implementation of the same using the meta-data on older platforms.

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html